# Is there a way to open a new Google Chrome tab from another application without Chrome being focused and raised?

Tags: google-chrome, window-focus

When reading emails containing multiple links, eg Quora digest, I like to open all the links in tabs the background, then read each tab in turn after I've finished with the email. This works with webmail running in the default browser if I middle-click (Linux) or Cmd-click (Mac), but if I try the same in a mail app, Chrome jumps to the front for every link. The combination of Mac's default mail reader and Safari also seems to let me open links in the background this way, but I prefer Chrome so I can sync across all my devices.

Does Chrome have an option not to focus a new tab opened from the command line?

Comment: I'm fairly sure the answer is no. Why Mail and Safari work together is because they're both Apple products, so they can code it this way; similar to how MSOffice apps work together. But MacOS is closed source, so Chrome devs don't have access to the same APIs and can't make it happen. I'm not posting an answer yet as it's just my logic - one who uses Chrome on MacOS might actually have a solution for you. Although I might search for one in [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) where the HC Apple geeks hang out :-) If you do, please delete this - cross-posting is frowned upon.

Comment: It should still be possible for non-Apple apps to do this on MacOS, Linux and Windows, as long as Chrome is already open. AIUI when a 3rd party app opens a link in Chrome, it runs a launcher which forwards the request to an existing instance of the browser. So it just requires the launcher to have an option not to raise and focus. The mailer would have to be aware of it, but that could be patched in to open source, or at worst, make that the default behaviour for Chrome. Unfortunately that isn't fully open source, and Google sync has been removed from Chromium.

Comment: Ah, the operative word of IT - "should" :-D Apparently it isn't. If your issue is with _Chromium_, not _Chrome_, you should edit your question. If I understand you correctly, what you're referring to is simply browser opening new tabs in background without stealing focus. Last time I tested either browser, that ability was there. I'm still sticking to my guns; it'd require an API access or similar that's not available in closed source (especially Apple), and the guys in Apple community might actually _know_ about this, maybe even have a workaround :-)

Comment: Please note - I'm not claiming I know how it works. I'm just making an educated guess based on how I've seen the industry work over the years. Apple has always been clever. Unlike MS they've never claimed Safari or iTunes is an integral part of the operating system. You're quite free to use whatever you want. They've just made sure that their apps and devices work seamlessly together (again ref MS Office) providing small conveniences which neither have nor ever will be available with 3rd party applications.

Comment: Chromium and Chrome are practically identical, except that Chromium is missing a couple of closed source components, which now includes Google sync, but this could apply equally to Firefox or Edge. They can all open new tabs without stealing focus, but only Safari makes that choice available to external programs. The others don't need any special Apple magic to make it possible, just a command-line switch.

Comment: Another possibility is a gnome-shell extension. It's quite easy to write one for general purpose focus-stealing prevention, and possible, but not so easy, to make it smart by detecting whether the last click was middle-click etc. But seeing as gmail's webmail interface isn't too bad, and I don't know of any other mailer with a killer feature since Thunderbird's ExternalEditor extension stopped working (and Claws Mail, which had a similar feature IIRC, is still stuck on GTK2) the incentive isn't quite there.

Comment: I'm a troubleshooter, in case of a problem I don't think in terms of "practically identical". A lesson learned after spending 2 weeks chasing ghosts :-) If I was troubleshooting this, I'd start testing with different browsers, email clients and OS:s; then start looking at similarities and differences between working and failing combinations... at the end we're both making guesses here, approach the question from different viewpoints, neither of which invalidate the other... :-) I still think you should drop this to the Apple board just because that's where the experts hang out :-)

Comment: My guess is that Google simply didn't bother exposing an option to open new tabs without focusing the window. I'm not just guessing that it could be done (at least on Linux), I know it could. I've written a tabbed application and know that this isn't some sort of magic that only Apple can achieve. You actually have to [call a specific function](https://github.com/realh/roxterm/blob/a08dfb9c7dc2ef76f1342d5f3e1ff262ff4b47e3/src/multitab.c#L2316) to focus/raise a window when adding a tab. Make that call optional, and it would do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a long-standing bug with Chromium (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=854609). [Comment 22](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=854609#c22) specifically says why this is a difficult (and most likely will never be fixed) bug.